# How to configure AAD secured Web API to grant access from B2C registred web application

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to Azure and as well as to *Azure Active Directory B2C*. As we are moving from AD to B2C, starting from the internal AD users. I registered my client application in Azure B2C in ABC tenant. I have policy to login as internal AD users. I have some existing APIS which is in XYZ tenant and registered in AAD. I want to use existing APIs, as I am not allowing any external users for time being. Its explicitly for internal users.

What are the steps to configure the APIs so it can be used by client application registered in B2C?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to clarify your question a bit further, e.g. avoiding using misleading abbreviations or even linking them to a (Wikipedia) definition. I also added the tag [active-direcory] for you.

Comment: I have a application registered in b2c in ABC tenant. I have an existing API registered in AAD in XYZ tenant. I want to expose the AAD API of XYZ tenant to client application registered in b2c in ABC tenant so that I can use it rather registering a fresh one again in B2C. Please let me know if the requirements are clear

Comment: Well, maybe to me, but (still) not too the wider audience. For instance, "in b2c" is not very clear. Looking forward to your edit.

Comment: Well, client application registered in b2c tenant (ABC.onmicrosoft.com). Existing apis are in AD tenant (XYZ.onmicrosoft.com). I need to access the apis of AD tenant from client application registered in b2c tenant